# Remove trailing zeros

Tags: magento-1.9

Im setting up Google trusted stores and I need to call some information which I can do but the format is wrong.

From what I can see there is 2 extra zero's at the and of the numbers which I need to remove.

Required format: "123.45"
Your value: "123.4500".

```
$orderId = $this->getOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
$address = $order->getShippingAddress();
```

The code I need to modify is:

```
<span id="gts-o-total"><?php echo $order->getGrandTotal(); ?></span>
<span id="gts-o-discounts">-<?php echo $order->getDiscountAmount(); ?></span>
<span id="gts-o-tax-total"><?php echo $order->getTaxAmount(); ?></span>
<span class="gts-i-price"><?php echo $item->getBasePrice(); ?></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  basic PHP float with 2 decimal places concept.

See at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706519/php-float-with-2-decimal-places-00

here you need to  change.

`$order->getGrandTotal()` to `number_format((float)$order->getGrandTotal(),2);`

`$order->getDiscountAmount()` to `number_format((float)$order->getDiscountAmount(),2);`

`$order->getTaxAmount()` to `number_format((float)$order->getTaxAmount(),2);`

`$item->getBasePrice()` to `number_format((float)$item->getBasePrice(),2);`

Comment: Hey, so i just add this to my current helper list? as that didnt work. Is there something else I need to be doing also? Thanks.

Comment: answet update,please check..

Comment: Still didnt work :(

Comment: I got: Your value: "<span class="price">£1.00</span>".

Comment: How would I use stripTags()

Comment: I am half way there with `echo strip_Tags($order->formatPrice($order->getGrandTotal()));` Just need to remove the currency symbol now

Comment: It does not work properly.My suggestio to use number_format

Comment: Will check your example now :)

Comment: @MikeTimTurner If the answer has helped you please be generous to upvote it. I see many answers here which provide good solutions but still are  zero-voted.

Comment: Nice answer @AmitBera